# GHC flags environment variable

Tags: haskell

I'm wondering if there is an environment variable where I can set default GHC options, such as `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns`, `-fwarn-incomplete-uni-patterns` or `-Wall`, analogous to `CFLAGS`.

I've couldn't find anything in google, and the `man` page only revealed `GHCRTS`, but not sure if that's the variable I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you tried `alias ghc='ghc $GHCFLAGS'`?

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but I thought I would mention it anyway....  On a package by package basis, you can add it in the "ghc-options:" line in the .cabal package.  This also strikes me as the correct way to do things, compile options should be specified per package, otherwise you might get different than expected results from a cabal install.

Comment: @jamshidh I'm aware of that, however I was looking forward to put some common options by default (mainly warnings) that I'll probably forget when creating a package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is not. I opened [GHC Trac ticket #9500](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9500) requesting this a few months ago, but it hasn't attracted much attention. Frankly, even I don't think it would be such a terrifically valuable feature. But if you want to try implementing it, you're more than welcome to!